# What is the difference between a logical connective and a logical gate?

Tags: formalisation

I understand that any *logical gate* is a "physical" or "concrete" implementation (say, in an electronic circuits board) of a corresponding *logical connective* which is a purely philosophical or purely mathematical form of a "logical gate".

What is the difference between a logical connective and a logical gate?

Comment: Considering that the post itself answers the title question, what is the question for us?

Comment: Hello dear @Conifold - I generally always enjoy reading your comments and your answers and have learned a lot from you from time to time in this website --- I am not sure the title suffices an answer. I am quite lost in understanding why you think it does. I really try to understand if the difference I myself presented from "prior research" as it is named here is correct or not. You are most welcome to answer (I guess I'll be happy to read this answer too!).

Comment: It is correct. Logical formulas are built with connectives and electronic circuits implementing them with the corresponding gates. Truth values of letters in a formula serve as inputs for the circuit and the resulting truth value of the formula as its output. In other words, gates implement the classical (truth functional) connectives. It is hard to tell from the post what you are looking for beyond that.

Comment: That's basically the kind of answer I expected to.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between a logical connective and a logical gate?

A [logical gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) "is an idealized model of computation or physical electronic device implementing a Boolean function, a logical operation performed on one or more binary inputs that produces a single binary output."

The "basic" ones implement the boolean connectives: not, and, or (see the corresponding [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Truth_tables)).

> logic gates can be cascaded in the same way that Boolean functions can be composed, allowing the construction of a physical model of all of Boolean logic, and therefore, all of the algorithms and mathematics that can be described with Boolean logic.

In conclusion, we have a physical implementation (see everyday electronic devices) of a mathematical model of computation, that is based on [Boolean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).